# ArUco program from scratch

Tags: c++, opencv, build, compilation, augmented-reality

I'm using the ArUco library with OpenCV (more information [here](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26)) but I can't find a way to build and run a program from scratch.

Once I installed the library I have access to different examples but if I want for instance to create a new file and add the library headers inside it, how can I compile and run it ? (with a command line or IDE, anything is fine)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent and email to the library's author and he added clear instructions at the end of the project webpage :)

Comment: remember to check your answers as "accepted" if you have a good answer that explains correctly your question

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to learn how to use your IDE's, compilation tools and general compilation basic stuff. This is not a question related to Aruco, or mostly any other tags you have set.

Try to lean CMake first, 'cause Aruco compilation is based on CMake: http://www.cmake.org/

You can start by just editing the aruco_simple example.

For a IDE that works right away with CMake you can try either Qt Creator >3.1 or KDevelop. Both free.